# Apcupsd run script?

Tags: 18.04, cpu, cpufreq

I want apcupsd to run a sript on the master computer in case the power is missing for my ups i have according to the guide from apcupsd added it in this folder:

/Etc/apcupsd

And called it: "doshutdown"

And chmod + x

It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh 192.168.1.183 sudo shutdown -P 0
ssh 192.168.1.189 sudo shutdown -P 0

exit 99
```

I have created a ssh private key and added the following to the computer to be shut down:

```
sudo visudo

yourusername ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

I can run the command from the terminal and shut down the machine on my network but apcupsd will not run my script any bid on why?

Comment: Have you tried the `ssh 192.168.1.183 sudo shutdown -P 0` as `ssh 192.168.1.183 'sudo shutdown -P 0'`?

Comment: no what is the difference ?

Comment: Single quoting the command to be sent via ssh since there are switches involved.  It helps avoid confusion as to where the switches are supposed to go.

Comment: I have tried now it does not work unfortunately :(

Comment: Maybe look into https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2249211.html